# table-row not 100% of table container (fieldset)

Tags: css

Why is the `.item` element which acts as a `table-tow` won't be 100% width
 of it's parent `table`-acting element?

Demo page: http://jsbin.com/AdaCUYu/8/edit

#### HTML

```
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <div class="item">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input />
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input />
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

#### CSS

```
fieldset{ 
  border:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  border-spacing:10px;
}

.item{ display:table-row; }
  .item > *{ display:table-cell; padding:5px; }
  .item input{ width:100%; }
```

Comment: not it's not the case. yes you can make it, I've done that for years.

Comment: nothing about this is experimental, it's old CSS 2.1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, found the problem. Seems like a `fieldset` element will not work as a `table`-displayed element. 
How strange.